# ERROR 1064 (42000) when running .sql script

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL 5.5.31

The script I am trying to run is:

```
drop table if exists TRV_ACCT
/

CREATE TABLE TRV_ACCT (
  ACCT_NUM varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  ACCT_NAME varchar(50),
  ACCT_TYPE varchar(100),
  ACCT_FO_ID decimal(14,0),
  OBJ_ID varchar(36),
  VER_NBR decimal(8,0) DEFAULT 0,
  SUB_ACCT varchar(10),
  SUB_ACCT_NAME varchar(50),
  CREATE_DT datetime,
  SUBSIDIZED_PCT float,
  PRIMARY KEY (ACCT_NUM)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

and the error info is:

```
mysql> \. create_travel_tables.sql
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '/

CREATE TABLE TRV_ACCT (
  ACCT_NUM varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  ACCT_NAME varchar(' at line 2
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `/` is an internal command of the SQL*Plus program bundled with Oracle. It has nothing to do with MySQL.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: to be precise: `/` is not really a "command", it's an (alternate) statement delimiter.

Comment: Replace the `/` with the correct statement terminator: the `;`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oracle [calls it "command"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12004.htm) and I think it's more a command than a mere delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is stated exactly in the error message:

You have a `/` in the second row, that does not belong there!